# Flatten and manipulate nested JSON structure using Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

I have this `JSON` structure:

```
"A": {
       "B": {
              "C": "D"
            }
     },
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
{
  "B" : "D"
}
```

using `Jackson`(I am using `v2.10.0`).

By using `@JsonUnwrapped` on the model, i can get:

```
"B": {
        "C": "D"
     }
```

If you need further information, i am happy to provide.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved(was easier than i thought) and in case it helps someone:

(1) I added another @JsonUnwrapped on the class `B` model
(2) On class `C`, i added @JsonProperty to rename the key to `B`.

Voila, simple hack!